# Appengine Cron job failed but no log whatsoever

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

Right now I am only seeing this:

[image]

I've checked my logs and couldn't find any reason for this failure.

I've written test cases to verify that this query returns status code 200

How can I find out what's causing this?

Comment: A fail means it did not return a 200 when it ran.  I suggest going to the logs, and doing a search for "AppEngine-Google".  Those will be the cron jobs and taskqueues.  Look at the 18:55:57 time to see if you can spot the http code returned. Other than that, add some logging to your view processor to see what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dig deep enough, the log entry is actually DEBUG not ERROR or anything.

0.1.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2014:17:55:58 -0700] "GET /device/alive HTTP/1.1" 404 87 - "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "saslkdalskdn.appspot.com" ms=6 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000010 ...

Answer (score 4):

You will find a log entry using that timestamp. Then you have to look at the http status code return by the server for clues:

```
                                                                    _______
                                                                   |       |
                                                                   | Here! |
                                                                   |__   __|
                                                                      \ /
                                                                       V 
0.1.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2014:17:55:58 -0700] "GET /device/alive HTTP/1.1" 404 87
 - "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)"
"saslkdalskdn.appspot.com" ms=6 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000010 ...
```

Here you can see the response code was 404, ie. "Not Found". (See other [http status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes))

*Any excuse for a bit of ascii art!*